# Identifying whether training dataset is imbalanced in CART

Tags: machine-learning, classification, prediction

I'm new to machine learning domain. I want to build a Classification tree for Binary classification of data.

I have a training data set of 269 records out of which 56 records belong to 'yes' class and 213 records to 'no' class.

Is this data imbalanced for building CART model? Do I need to undersample 'no' class records? Also from Gini index, Chi-Square and Information Gain, which algorithm is best for node splitting?

P.S.:- I can't increase the size of the dataset further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your data is not balanced.

Before applying any kind of modeling it is suggestible to balance the data, you can use packages like **SMOTE,ROSE** to overcome the imbalance in your data.

For your next question, which index to use: It is subjective to your data. Please go through these links [Link-1](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-information-gain-and-gini-index-When-should-I-apply-each-of-the-method), [Link-2](http://www.learnbymarketing.com/481/decision-tree-flavors-gini-info-gain/) for better understanding but suggestible to try both Entropy and Gini Impurity. There is a good chance to get similar trees and similar outcome.

Gain Ratio works better to reduce bias towards highly branching features like time, salary etc. (Information about the features of the dataset isn’t mentioned)

Do let me know if you have any additional questions.

Finally, how big is your test dataset?

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I will try to balance data. Can you tell me the minimum ratio of yes to no class where we can say the data is balanced enough? Actually, I used same data for naive Bayesian classifier which gave me 86% accuracy. That's why I ignored balancing in first place.

Comment: 50% yes and 50% no is called as balanced data. Even NB might give you good result but it is not standard or fixed but it is important to balance the data.

Comment: My test data set is very small. only 35 records are there. What your thoughts on it?

Comment: It all depends on your training set not on test set.  You use test set to access the models accuracy and its performance.

Comment: ok. Thanks. I tried reading about SMOTE but due to lack of knowledge in machine learning, I didn't understand it very well. So I reduced data set to 219 records. Now I have 85 records of yes class and 135 of no class. Is this enough for the CART? Also, I have a deadline for this college project, that's why I'm doing it by learning only related machine learning stuff for my project. :(

Comment: That should be fine, you can get some decent results. But 50-50 is ideal.

Comment: Got it. I really appreciate your help on this problem. If you don't mind, is there any way I can contact you in future If I've some doubts?

Comment: Yeah I think you can comment here. If necessary we can even make a private chat group. 

Comment: today I tried to build CART model using sklearn. I'm getting only 58% accuracy. Can you help me?

Comment: Hey, was kind of occupied with office work. tell me how can i help you?

Comment: I'm getting very low accuracy in CART. How to increase it? Used same training dataset for naive bayes and gettiing 88% accuracy

Comment: in caret which model are you using exactly? Logistic Regression?

Comment: decision tree classifier from sklearn. Using as it is. and gini for splitting purpose

Comment: Then try applying Naives Bayes Classifier now and see how does it behave

Comment: did it. It performs well. 88% accuracy. But doesn't work with cart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72109/discussion-between-scorpionk-and-toros91).